Kubuntu 24.04 and AMD graphic card, correct refresh rate not available
I have an odd issue. I have a single Dell monitor (S2716DG if it makes any difference), by default using 2560x1440 resolution. When I'm using a default (it is the highest one), the best refresh rate is available (144hz).

But, when I want to use lower resolution, 144hz is gone and only 60hz is available.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue? I tried to use cvt to add new mode using xrandr, but it doesn't work, screen just goes black when I try to use the new mode. This is the output of xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95 + 144.00*  120.00    99.95    84.98    23.97  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.95  
   1600x1200     59.95  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     59.95  
   1440x900      59.95  
   1280x800      59.95  
   1280x720      59.95  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I tried to install amdgpu drivers from AMD website, but with them it doesn't work at all, looks like they're not compatible with 24.04 yet.
Is there anything I can do to enable the missing refresh rate?
